# XML as Interexchange data instead of Beans in EJB3 ...Is this possible

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

Is there any spec in EJB3.x where exchange of Data between Client ( web / mobile ...) and EJB3 (Java EE) Server is done **using XML instead of Using Java Beans**.

If any example /URL exists ...please direct ..... ;(

> I know that there is SOAP Services.....but my intention is not in
>   favor of using the same.

Reason : Payload would become lighter on all channels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all EJB3 beans define a web view that uses JAX-WS. For this you need to add the `@WebService` annotation to a stateless bean.

But as you don't want to use SOAP, the other alternative is JAX-RS. The EJB3 spec itself doesn't mention any support for this, but the other way around JAX-RS has explicit support for EJB.

Any full Java EE 6 implementation already comes with JAX-RS, so there's typically nothing extra that you need to install. Just annotating your beans with `@Produces` and `@Path` with appropriate values should be enough to get you started.